# Read currency & % using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read an excel file using Apache Poi (v3.11 / XSSFWorkbook ). I am reading a particular sheet {e.x. sheet(0)} which is formed by different macros from around 15 sheets from the same file. The issue is I am able to read the non formatted String data but unable to read formatted data like currency or %.

I do not control the excel worksheet anyway. I will be reading the file from a network share path.

```
XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = null
    XSSFSheet mySheet = null;
    Row rowHeader = null;
    Row rowData = null;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
            new File(
                    "inputfile.xlsx"));
    myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
    rowHeader = mySheet.getRow(0);
    rowData = mySheet.getRow(1);



        for (Cell s : rowHeader) {  
                System.out.print("|  "+s.getStringCellValue());
                System.out.println(" -->"+getCellValue(myWorkBook,rowData.getCell(s.getColumnIndex())));
    }

    myWorkBook.close();
}
//   $#,##0.00

private static String getCellValue(XSSFWorkbook wb, Cell cell)
{
   XSSFCell x = (XSSFCell)cell;
   return x.getRawValue();
}
}
```

I have a excel sheet like below

```
Name    Amount    Rate
Name1   $1,500  75%
```

If I read the above sheet using this code

Name --> Name1

Amount --> 1500 ( note the missing $ and , )

Rate --> 74.99999998 (number inacurate and missing % symbol)

Comment: Consider using `BigDecimal` to store your currency values.

Comment: do you need $ symbol, % with values.

Comment: the macro generates $ & %. I can see these values if I open the sheet with Ms-excel. And yes I do need $ & %. Objective is to get the cell values exactly seen in the cell.

Comment: no, what i mean. we read those values. you need those values only or with symbol

Comment: with symbol need those values. If the cell shows(macro output) "$1,500" I should be able to read this as "$1,500" not 1500.

Comment: you read those values as string

Comment: you can only read as String only the cells which are set as 'Text' in excel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93382/discussion-between-kumaresan-perumal-and-avinandan012).

Comment: What happens if you use [DataFormatter to render the cell to a String](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html)?

Comment: @ Gagravarr thanks DataFormatter solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Thanks  @Gagravarr

this below code solved the issue

```
private static String getCellValue(XSSFWorkbook wb, Cell cell)
{
  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
  String formattedCellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
  return formattedCellValue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation,

[getRawValue()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getNumericCellValue()) would return the raw, underlying ooxml value.

Use [`getStringCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getStringCellValue()) instead as it return the value as a String and nothing is lost.

Comment: As I stated getStringCellValue() works if the cell is of Type 'Text'. For numbers(Type : Currency / Number /Percentage) you will get  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell". Even if you write a logic using getCellType() to avoid this you loose the formatting information