# Problem in reading Numeric value form Excel file using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have one Column in numeric and the value is 0.142  but convert to 0.14200000000000002

This is my code , I use  cell.getNumericCellValue()

```
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC : 
vaTmpVal = String.valueOf(voCel.getNumericCellValue());
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349241/read-currency-using-java) post on ApachePOI

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the code rather than a link to an image. Use the code formatting, so that everything is easy to read within the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cell.getNumericCellValue()` gets numeric cell values exact as they are stored. But `Excel` always uses only 15 significant digits for numeric values. So the exact value `0.14200000000000002` (having 17 significant digits) will be `0.142` for `Excel`.

If the need is to get all cell values as string, then you should not get the cell values by `CellType`. Instead you should using `apache poi`'s [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html). The `DataFormatter.formatCellValue` method gets all cell values as strings by formatting them the same kind as `Excel` will do. So if `Excel` shows `0.142` as the cell value then also `DataFormatter` will get `0.142` even if the exact numeric cell value is `0.14200000000000002`.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Locale;

class GetDataFromExcelUsingDataFormatter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelExample.xlsx"));

  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
  FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
    System.out.println(cellValue);
   }
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers, as you understand them in a base-10 numbering system (i.e. 0 - 9), cannot be accurately represented in binary (i.e. 0 - 1). Thus, most of the time what you'll see (from a programming language construct) is an approximation of the value.

In your case, if you don't care about the precision of your values past the thousandths position, you can use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("0.000").format(0.142));
    }
}
```

Just for your reference as well, this [exact question](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30565) has been asked on poi's bug tracker and has been closed as "RESOLVED INVALID".

Additionally, as a fun little experiment to prove out the above, execute the following in a jshell session:

```
% jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> 0.1*0.1
$1 ==> 0.010000000000000002
```

You'd expect the above answer to be only 0.01; however, that's not the case.